# Assuming all required header files are included, What will be the output?

Tags: c++

```
void position (int & C1, int C2=3)
{
   C1 += 2;
   C2 += 1;
}

int main()
{
   int P1 = 20, P2 = 4;
   position(P1);
   cout<<P1<<","<<P2<<endl;
   position (P2,P1);
   cout<<P1<<","<<endl;
}
```

Assuming all required header files are included, What will be the output?

Comment: Have you tried just running it and see? Or is "What's the output?" not your actual question?

Comment: The output is `error: use of undeclared identifier 'cout'`.

Comment: A better question will be: When I run this program I get output "X". However, i was expecting "Y" as output. Can somebody explain why?

Comment: try using `std::cout` and `std::endl`

Comment: OP: If what @RSahu mentions fits your problem, also include why exactly you expected "Y".

Comment: @Wilfred You forgot to specify P2 in this output statement cout<<P1<<","<<endl;

Answer (score 1):

In fact the function

```
void position (int & C1, int C2=3)
{
   C1 += 2;
   C2 += 1;
}
```

can be rewritten like

```
void position( int & C1, int = 3)
{
   C1 += 2;
}
```

because the second parameter is not used in the function and does not have a side effect.

Thus only the first argument passed to the function by reference is changed.

In the first call

```
position(P1);
```

the first argument is P1. So P1 is changed by this call.

In the second call

```
position (P2,P1);
```

the first argument is P2. So P2 is changed by this call.